# Allowing Android system apps to move to SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have a requirement to enable my apps to have the **move to sd card** feature enabled.
For this I changed the `installLocation` to `auto`. This worked when the app was installed for the first time i.e as a standalone app.

We happen to have the app as System app in some OEMs. 
In those cases, changing the `installLocation` to `auto` didn't work.

So, here are my queries:

- Is `installLocation` forced to `internalOnly` for system apps?
- Is there a way to allow system apps to move to sd card (by code)?
- Also, if a system app gets updated with new manifest wherein `installLocation` changes from `internalOnly` to `auto`, shouldn't that allow movement to SD card?
- Can OEM (Mobile manufacturer like Samsung, LG, etc) decide on enabling "Move to SD card"  feature for a system app and what are the consequences for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is installLocation forced to internalOnly for system apps?

yes, you are right they are store in internal storage.

2. Is there a way to allow system apps to move to sd card (by code)?

No, you can't move these apps to external storage by code or from settings.

3. Also, if a system app gets updated with new manifest wherein installLocation changes from internalOnly to auto, shouldn't that allow movement to SD card?

I don't thing so they are updated like these as you mention above.
Also, in Auto system decides where to store application whether on internal storage or in external storage

please refer below link for reference.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

please let me know if you are still confuse.

Comment: Thanks Jitesh. I had read the link and assumed the same. One query: does it matter if the system apps are installed in system folder or data folder?

Comment: Also, any idea as to how can the OEM allow an app to move to sd card?

Comment: It should be system storage, assume that you are storing system apps in external storage and one day you removed external card then your device probably not work fine.

Comment: I am still awaiting some response wrt how it can be done be it by the app developer or the oem. If there is none, I will accept it.

Comment: What do you mean by oem ? full form ?

Comment: NO, oem can't depends on external card, as so many people not even use sd card that time it will become disaster.